# Mysql INSERT ... on duplicate key update if value is diffrent else delete

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates

I have a set of buttons that only one of them can be selected at a time and they can be toggled off, meaning that if user selects a selected button again it should be deselected.
Lets say that my table has on `buttons_id`,`user_id` and `value` columns, `buttons_id` and `user_id` are the primary keys(joined together).
So i want to

- insert the selected `value` to table if `buttons_id`,`user_id` combo doesn't exist (`insert into`)
- update the record if `buttons_id`,`user_id` combo exist and value is different (`on duplicate key update`)
- delete the record if `buttons_id`,`user_id` combo exist and value is the same (`delete ?`)

how can i do this is a single query ? can i use `case` inside `on duplicate key update` ?

Comment: I don't see a way that you can [INSERT/UPDATE] and [DELETE] in a single statement. Note that the action is the very first thing you write within a statement.

Comment: A button state is something that is best handled in your app in variables (or the button component itself). Otherwise you would have to query the database again after the update to see which button is active now (although you just pressed it in your app). And if only one button can be active, as far as I understand it your approach would not work, because pressing a specific button would not deselect the others. So just update one row per `user_id` (primary key), and the last pressed button as `button_id`, and its (known) state as `value` (or with `case` if you really want to switch in db).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a transaction (requires that your table uses a transactional storage engine, such as InnoDB):

1. Start a transaction.  This is usually best done via an appropriate call to whatever API you're using, but if you absolutely have to do it in SQL then you can do:

   ```
   START TRANSACTION
   ```
2. Issue a [locking read](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) to discover the current value:

   ```
   SELECT `value` FROM `table` WHERE buttons_id = ? AND user_id = ? FOR UPDATE
   ```
3. Perform the business logic in your client application, according to the result received above—i.e. issue `INSERT` if no result, `UPDATE` if `value` differed or `DELETE` if `value` matched.
4. Commit the transaction.  Again, this is usually best done via an API call, but if you're doing it in SQL:

   ```
   COMMIT
   ```